# Make google crawl a site when it is cloaked

Tags: google-crawlers, cloaking

I host this website. And I order a domain for it. SO the site is hosten on somedomain.be/boring

I added a domain www.company.com

Now In the webmastertools of google if I want to add the property they wil not verify it despite the DNS record, TXT, TAG, and file.

How Can I fix this? [image]

[image]

Comment: How is this a programming question? And how long ago did you set up the hosting? It takes time for DNS replication; it's not instantaneous, where you create the site and 2 seconds later the whole world can find it.

Comment: Well I added the site yesterday. But normally I just use the file and that works. But I'm new to the URL forwarding so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the config to HTTP redirect. That way it can be crawled but then I changed it back to cloaking again.